# How to run node cmd in heroku profile script

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm trying to run an inline node script in heroku, inside a custom .profile.d script but somehow `node` is not defined at that time.

Basically something like this:

`VAR1=$(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/somerepohere/pulls?access_token=some_token_here | node -pe "let pr = JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync('/dev/stdin').toString())")`

The app is a React app, deployed using https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack.

Maybe it's not even possible to execute node in that step, so any leads will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#an-example-one-off-dyno

Comment: @PatrickRoberts thanks... was not aware of that. I just tested and I got the correct path for node.